# Redirect to subdomain without forwarding query strings in urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I am trying to redirect from root domain to a subdomain like example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) redirect to blog.example.com. I want to retain the path but remove the query strings.
For example. example.com/abc-def/ (both www and non www versions) redirect to `blog.example.com/abc-def/`.
However, `example.com/abc-def/?p=219` must redirect to `blog.example.com/abc-def/`

I mean I want to forward the entire domain to the subdomain but no query strings in the url need to be forwarded. Only the url path is retained and any query strings at the end of the urls are removed. What rules I must add to .htaccess file to achieve this? Please let me know.

I am unable to find the right rule. Please help me set up the right redirect. If I try to remove the query strings, it redirects only to the home page.
Here is the redirect rule I tried from my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://blog.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

But it is not having any effect.

Comment: I have added the  particular rule from my .htaccess file to the question. There are not many rules in the file except this and a www redirect rule.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this redirect rule in site root .htaccess of `example.com`:

```bash
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://blog.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Note that `%{REQUEST_URI}` in target will retain same URI path as in the original URL in target however `?` after that will discard any pre-existing query string.

Make sure to test this change in a new browser or via command line curl.

Comment: I used an external redirect service since my initial options did not work out. I will try again and if it works I will let you know.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Thanks for the help. What do I do if I do not want to redirect the path as well? For example, everything from firstwebsite.com goes to the homepage of secondwebsite.com. No redirecting either path or query strings. I need to test. Please replay soon.

Comment: In that case 2nd line in above code would be just `RewriteRule ^ https://blog.example.com/? [L,R]`